# Ruby: Call parent method from internal class

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

For example, I have something like that (Ruby 1.9.1):

```
class Chef::Recipe::MyFancyFeature
  def my_action do
    search(:node, 'repice[common]')
  end
end
```

I assume that there is NOT difference as this way:

```
class Chef
  class Recipe
    class MyFancyFeature
      def my_action do
        search(:node, 'repice[common]')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and my second part of question (most important): Method `search` is defined in `Chef::Recipe` and how I can call it from my `MyFancyFeature` class ?

Comment: this is example and simplyfied part of code

Comment: What is the first part of your question?

Comment: any difference between `Chef::Recipe::MyFancyFeature` and `class Cheff class Recipe class MyFancyFeature` ?

Comment: If you have two questions, please ask two questions. However, note that your first question has already been asked numerous times on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad 1) Yes, they are the same

ad 2) If you want to call `search` from `Chef::Recipe`, you have to do:

```
class Chef
  class Recipe
    def search(arg1, arg2)
      # your logic here
      p arg1
      p arg2
    end

    class MyFancyFeature
      def my_action
        Recipe.new.search(:node, 'repice[common]')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Paweł. Now I can understand that it's nested class inside `Recipe` and from `MyFancyFeature` I don't have access to instance variables of `Recipe`. Am I correct ?

Comment: Well, you don't have access "directly" (and by "directly" I mean `@your_var`), but you can expose your attributes via accessor methods (eg. `attr_accessor :your_var`). Keep in mind that `Recipe` is just a class, even if you're trying to do that within `MyFancyFeature`

Comment: I'm really unsure on how it would behave within a chef run as you're already in a Recipe instance when you'll call `MyFancyFeature::my_action` The recomended way to achieve that is using library with Module and then send them into Recipe namespace. See [this for exemple](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt/blob/master/libraries/helpers.rb)